# rebuild ipa file using appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Titanium Appcelerator to build an iPad app. I have my iPad provisioned and everything, however when I try to run the app on "iOS Device" from the Appcelerator menu it opens up iTunes and tries to install / sync the app on the iPad. The problem with this is that the computer I"m using to develop is not the main computer for the iPad, so I don't want it to sync. I'm using the iphone configuration utility, and just going through the titanium workspace until I find the .app or .ipa. I am using TestFlight to beta test, and import the ipa into that and it sends it off to a few devices. The problem is, I updated the app in appcelerator, but the .ipa (or .app) file never updated. Is there a way to do a fresh build so it will regenerate the .ipa file? Also is there a way to run the app from the computer (while it's plugged in) so you can still use the log and info terminal using titanium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.7.x of Titanium, The .ipa of your app will be in the build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos directory of your Titanium project - that is what you can (and are) uploading to TestFlight.  To force a rebuild, just delete everything in the build/iphone directory (including subdirectories) and do a 'Run on Device' build it again.  This will give you a fresh build and fresh ipa.

If you are using the new Titanium Studio and have paid to be a Indie developer, it should have the ability run your application on your device, but I haven't tested it.

Before Titanium Studio, I rolled my own tracer that I can turn on and off.  [Details are here](http://www.titaniumdevelopment.com.au/blog/2010/06/20/finding-performance-bottlenecks-titanium-mobile-for-ipad/).